# Which is the best way to debug PHP in WordPress?

Tags: php, debugging, wordpress, popup, logging

I have tried several methods to debug PHP code in a hosted WordPress 3.1 installation, however nothing seems to offer what I need. Both plugin based consoles and browser based consoles create more problems that the ones that I need to solve.

I am looking for a simple text/html popup window that will launch as soon as the code hits a function in the code. The function argument (debug info) can just be displayed in the popup.

At the same time ideally would be to record all the debug info in a log file on my desktop.

Help!

Comment: though i don't really use a debugger for php, xdebug is a well known one. Have you tried that ?

Comment: If you're on shared host, your possibilites are limited; put the args for the function in a log, log publ. available for your browser. (and your desktop). KIS if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting with several methods & ways, for my purposes i concluded that dbug (http://dbug.ospinto.com/) is the quickest & cleanest way to get immediate and inline information & data on PHP objects, arrays, etc.

You just need to include the class and to call the function whenever you want. I used it for a wordpress / buddypress project and I was filtering the debug statements with my user account.

include it
`include_once("dBug.php");`

use it
`if($bp->loggedin_user->id == '4') {new dBug($entry);}  //dbug statement`

:)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it yet, but FirePHP looks promising for capturing loggin messages and the like. It's an addon to FireBug.

Answer (score 0):

FirePHP cannot print anything after the headers where sent. It is not a debugging method, but a logging method.
You need IDE like [CodeLobster](http://www.codelobster.com) or [PHPEdit](http://www.phpedit.com/en) (not free) or the best is [Zend Studio](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/)