# How to debug cart content in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, debugging, woocommerce, cart

Found the following code in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576667/get-cart-item-name-quantity-all-details-woocommerce/28576861#28576861):

```
<?php
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
        $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); 
        echo "<b>".$_product->get_title().'</b>  <br> Quantity: '.$values['quantity'].'<br>'; 
        $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
        echo "  Price: ".$price."<br>";
    } 
?>
```

I'm a rookie when it comes to adding code.

Simple question: **Where do I add this php code?**

I have a test site, and would like to see the cart data (in order to try add some other customized code).

Will it simply print onto the page? Will it replacing the standard cart view? Can I view both?
Optimally it would open a new small browser window or gadget to show the "raw" data.

Comment: I would say that the code goes in your functions.php. But I think some hooks or references are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add custom code to your site you first need to create a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/). Then, you will need to insert the custom code inside the [functions.php](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#using-functions-php) file of your active (child) theme.

If it's a staging/debug site you can use the [`woocommerce_before_cart`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-cart-cart.html#source-view.20) hook to print the contents of the variables. Another check that you could add is to check if the [current user is an administrator](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108765/if-admin-is-logged-in), so as not to see the data to other users of the site.

So it will be something like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'wc_cart_debug' );
function wc_cart_debug( $cart ) {

    if ( ! current_user_can('administrator') ) {
        return;
    }

    // Your code here.

}
```

**RELATED ANSWERS**

- [How to debug in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740111/how-to-debug-in-woocommerce-3)
- [PHP and WordPress: Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080679/php-and-wordpress-debugging)
- [How to debug php code while developing wordpress plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506601/how-to-debug-php-code-while-developing-wordpress-plugins)
- [Debugging in PHP and Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231813/debugging-in-php-and-wordpress)
- [Which is the best way to debug PHP in WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607189/which-is-the-best-way-to-debug-php-in-wordpress)